# Get the image from the server

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, server, axios

I uploaded an image file using axios post method and it was successfully uploaded to the server...
On return to the POST method, it returned the Image URL as:

```
{imageUrl: "/root/TTAppJava/images/players/Screenshot from 2020-11-24 16-38-57.png"}
```

Now, I want to display the image onto my screen.
How can I get that image?
I am using React.js to implement this.
The URL I used to post the image is:
`http://139.59.16.180:8269/player/details/${id}`

I am doing this to upload my data:

```
var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("file", image);
    const theWrapper = {
        "data": {
            "name": name,
            "age": age,
            "email": email,
            "gender": gender
        }
    }

    formData.append("theWrapper", JSON.stringify(theWrapper))

    Axios.post("http://139.59.16.180:8269/player/add",
        formData,
        { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token") } }
    ).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        alert("Player added successfully.")
        history.push("/players")
    })
        .catch(err => alert(err.messge))
```

And the response I am getting is:

```
{id: 14, name: "shreyas", email: "asdfjka@gmail.com", gender: "Male", imageUrl: "/root/TTAppJava/images/players/Screenshot from 2020-11-24 16-38-57.png", …}
```

Comment: What backend are you using? Is it your own? what language? You basically need to send the file from the server as Stream and that downloadUrl should be is image src tag.

Comment: we are using Spring Boot in backend and Sql as database.

Comment: @AlishGiri I have updated the details in my question if it is helpful. Please Help.

Comment: If you image is in local you need to expose a API in your Backend and return an Stream.
If you have an API then you can hit the API directly inside the img tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example how its done in Node app, since the underlying concept will be the same as I am not a Java developer.

First please note your image_url/download_url should be saved as follows,

```
https://yourdomain/folder/image_name

example: http://localhost:3000/uploads_folder/my_image_name.jpg
```

and then you need a route in Java Spring which figures out what image to send to the front-end as Stream like below,

```
 router.get("/:folder/:image_name", async (req, res) => {
  const { folder, image_name } = req.params;

  // find an image based on the downloadUrl in the folder where files are saved.
  // Please note, after uploading file successfully generate a download url 
  // appropriately so that this route can help figure out which image you 
  // are looking for.
  const file = path.join(`path/to/${folder}`, `${image_name}`);

  // Figure out a way how stream works in your context.
  // Providing MIME type is important!
  const type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || "image/jpg";
  const s = fs.createReadStream(file);
  s.on("open", () => {
    res.set("Content-Type", type);
    s.pipe(res);
  });
  s.on("error", (err) => {
    // Handle Error
  });
});
```